# Why is transition timing function working on the transform property but not the filter property even though I have transition: *all* 2s;

Tags: html, css

The transition property is working on my images like I intended with the exception of it applying to the saturation property? The scale works and smoothly transitions out over the amount of seconds I've dictated but the saturation doesn't.

I've checked I have the hover syntax right and even the example is functioning

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  display:flex;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 1s;
   filter: sepia(25%) saturate(100%) brightness(85%);
  
}
    .img:hover {
      transform:scale(1.2);
      filter: saturate(0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586889720013-37a246a378d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="" class="img">
  </figure>
  
    <figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586835319938-307d4746d12d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="img">
  </figure>
  

<figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562873656-65edf09f1b9b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80" alt="" class="img">
</figure>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not maintain the porperties you were using on the img element in the :hover part.

**Match your properties:**

```
img {
filter: sepia(25%) saturate(100%) brightness(85%);
}

img:hover {
filter: sepia(25%) saturate(100%) brightness(0);
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  display:flex;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 1s;
   filter: sepia(25%) saturate(100%) brightness(85%);
  
}
    .img:hover {
      transform:scale(1.2);
      /* You must include all the same properties that you included originally in the actual element */
      filter: sepia(25%) saturate(0) brightness(85%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586889720013-37a246a378d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="" class="img">
  </figure>
  
    <figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586835319938-307d4746d12d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="img">
  </figure>
  

<figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562873656-65edf09f1b9b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80" alt="" class="img">
</figure>



</div>
```